# For loop is not moving on to next file in folder

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, paste

I am trying to write a `for` loop that will grab information from each successive file in a folder and then paste this info into a `data.frame`. The file names only change by their year. As it stands, the `for` loop seems to be unable to move on to the next year and instead fills the data frame with first year's information only. I have set a working directory to the folder that contains all of the years. What command will change the year in the path name for each iteration of the loop, as in:

```
for (year in 2001:2011) {
  2001,2001+1, 2001+2, 2001+3, etc.
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to go about this, but here's one approach. Say I have a directory of files called `TempDir`, which contains the files

```
> list.files("F:/TempDir")
[1] "tempFile_2006.csv" "tempFile_2007.csv" "tempFile_2008.csv" "tempFile_2009.csv" "tempFile_2010.csv"
```

having the common root name `tempFile_`, followed by a year. Then you could selectively read in certain files into a list of `data.frame`s using something like this:

```
Years <- 2007:2010
dfList <- list(NULL)
length(dfList) <- length(Years)
##
for(i in 1:length(Years)){
  iPath <- paste0("F:/TempDir/tempFile_",Years[i],
                  ".csv")
  dfList[[i]] <- read.csv(
    file=iPath,
    header=TRUE)
  dfList
}
##
```

This gives me the following list of `data.frame`s:

```
> dfList
[[1]]
  X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10

[[2]]
  X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10

[[3]]
  X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10

[[4]]
  X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10
```

I wrote the same data to each of these files, but obviously if they contained different data sets the `data.frame`s in the `list` would not be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `lapply`.  Using @nrussell example data.  I named the files as `2006.csv`, `2007.csv` etc. in my `working directory`

```
 list.files(pattern="2\\d+.csv") #I used pattern argument as I have other files in the working directory which I don't want to read
 #[1] "2006.csv" "2007.csv" "2008.csv" "2009.csv" "2010.csv"

 lst <- lapply(list.files(pattern="2\\d+.csv"), 
       function(x) read.csv(x, header=TRUE, sep=""))

lst[1:2]
[[1]]
 X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10

[[2]]
X x  y
1 1 1  6
2 2 2  7
3 3 3  8
4 4 4  9
5 5 5 10
```

Comment: @nrussell Thanks, +1 for providing the data and of course the OP asked for `for` loop.